# style binding in angular 2 backgrounImage throw error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a application with angular 2,
this is my template :

```
<div class="cover_user_profile"
       [style.backgroundImage]="model.cover ? url(model.cover) : url('client/img/profile_user/test.png') ">
</div>
```

i think's angular2 think's url() is a function and throw an error...what is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` notation expects `expressions`, it tries to evaluate `url('kgfdgf')`, hence your error.

---

`[style.background-color]` is a possible binding, `[style.background-image]` is not ( [**`PLUNKER`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2C0f2r7EbtzL42V1FCC?p=preview) )

---

**Update:**

Which is a side-effect of sanitizing the css. See [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8701) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8491) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8686).

**Workaround:** [**`PLUNKER`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2C0f2r7EbtzL42V1FCC?p=preview)

Where [QuentinFchx](https://github.com/QuentinFchx) mentioned a workaround using pipe

```ts
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafePipe {
    constructor(sanitizer:DomSanitizationService){
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
    }

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Usage: `<div [style.transform]="'rotate(7deg)' | safe"> asdf </div>`

---

**Alternative:** [**`PLUNKER`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2C0f2r7EbtzL42V1FCC?p=preview)

```ts
 [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (model.cover || 'client/img/profile_user/test.png') + ')'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this valid expression:

```
<div class="cover_user_profile"
   [style.backgroundImage]="model.cover ? 'url(' + model.cover + ')' : 'url(client/img/profile_user/test.png)'">
</div>
```

As a matter of fact, `url` isn't a method but something specific to CSS that needs to be present in the final string.

Comment: but `[style.backgroundImage]` does nothing, even `[style.background-image]` has no effect, maybe it's not possible to add image with `[style.attribute]` notation ?

Comment: Mum I think you're right ;-) Perhaps it's because of the dash... +1 for your answer!

Comment: Thanks! .....  but `background-color` works , it might be a bug or just not supported by angular

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8686), let's see what comes out