# Angular 'filter' style binding not work

Tags: css, angular

There is an example

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div>
    <h2 style="background-color:green">
        No Filter
    </h2>
    </div>
    <div style="filter:brightness(0.5)">
    <h2 style="background-color:green">
        Filter with style.
    </h2>
    </div>
    <div [style.filter]="'brightness(' + val + ')'">
    <h2 style="background-color:green">
        Filter with style binding.
    </h2>
    </div>
    <p>filter binding express value: {{'brightness(' + val + ')'}}</p>
    `,
})
export class App {
    val = 0.5;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gD9xkX5aWrdNDyD6fnIh?p=preview

got the rendered result:

[image]

Seem like style binding [style.filter] not work. Anyone know the reason or give another way to control filter brightness style by component member value?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: [style.box-shadow] is not work too. Does Angular style binding just support limited css type? I can't find related document from Angular official website or Google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we apply the filter style like this:

```
<div [style.filter]="'brightness(' + val + ')'">
```

the following message appears in the console:

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value brightness(0.5)

The style expression `brightness(0.5)` is considered unsafe by Angular. We can mark it as safe by calling `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle` in a method of the component class or with the help of a custom pipe defined as:

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafePipe {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
    }

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

which can be applied like this in the template:

```
<div [style.filter]="'brightness(' + val + ')' | safe">
```

An alternative, which does not involve sanitization problems, is to use the `ngStyle` directive:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'filter': 'brightness(' + val + ')'}">
```

Both techniques are shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsvdxg).

The problem of unsafe style expressions has been discussed in other posts:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663363/1009922
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267875/1009922

Comment: I added an explanation and a solution for the problem with `[style.filter]`.